# npm start issue working on react and next .js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I just cloned code from a GitHub repository.
I tried to run it with the following command

```
 'next' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nextjs@0.1.0 start: `next start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nextjs@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-12T12_27_53_876Z-debug.log
PS F:\REACT\projectnamme> node -v
v12.16.1
PS F:\REACT\projectnamme> npm -v
6.13.4
F:\REACT\projectnamme> create-react-app --version
3.4.1
```

Comment: Did you install the dependencies?

Comment: you need to run a `npm install` first, or at least a `npm install next`.

Comment: i mean, this is the basics..., im sure the github repo has a readme, try to do some research before posting something

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to download your node_modules

you can use `npm install`  or `yarn install`

then do `npm start` or `yarn start` in your terminal